# ThreadLocal set() then immediately get() doesn't always pick up the value

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

I am having trouble reliably getting ThreadLocal values I just set. I've tried to construct a simple example to demonstrate the issue:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StackOverflowQuestion {

    private static ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(() -> {
                threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();
                threadLocal.set("foo");
                System.out.println(threadLocal.get());
            });
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        threadPool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

The output is:

> null
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> foo
>
> null
>
> foo
>
> foo

The positions of the `null` values vary each time. I would have expected all of them to be `foo`. Why can't I set the `threadLocal` and then immediately read the value I just set? Does it say this somewhere in the documentation or is this a JVM bug? In case it's relevant, I'm using Oracle Java JRE 1.8.0_172 on Windows.

Comment: You should not create a new ThreadLocal variable in every thread, you should reuse the same instance and then access this instance from different threads.

Comment: Because the first thread creates a new ThreadLocal variable, sets something on it, the second thread creates a new ThreadLocal variable which does not have ANY content and then the first one prints the content of that variable (Nothing).

Comment: D'oh! Thank you.

Comment: It is that he's creating new thread locals -- you'll get somewhat unpredictable behaviour with what's written.  The actual "ThreadLocal" reference itself should  shared by all threads.

Comment: also unless you really really know why you are doing `ThreadLocal` and that it is the only solution to your problem, it is a code smell / anti-patten and can in almost all cases be done in a better less bug prone way. This question proves this point.

Comment: Not sure why your were downvoted, this is a well-written question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new `ThreadLocal` repeatly.

You can imagine `ThreadLocal` works like a `Map`, with current thread as the key. And the code could lead to:

```
threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>(); ----> one thread create an empty ThreadLocal
threadLocal.set("foo");
System.out.println(threadLocal.get()); ----> another thread get null
```

You can change it to:

```
threadPool.execute(() -> {
    threadLocal.set("foo");
    System.out.println(threadLocal.get());
});
```